# How to skip the request dialog for inviting users from an app if user does not have any friend in their list?

Tags: facebook, dialog, request

I am using facebook request dialog box for invite my friends for an app. I added app_non_users and exclude_ids to filter the users. But once I invite all my friends need to skip this request dialog. Currently it is showing the message No results and couldn't redirect to the canvas page

here is the code

```
$requests_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id="
                . $appid . "&redirect_uri=" . $canvas_url."&message=" . $message. "&filters=" . json_encode($filters)."&exclude_ids=". json_encode($exclude_ids);

if (empty($_REQUEST["request"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url. "'</script>");           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "ask" facebook that in two ways:

(1) Using the [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you can make a request to: *[/me/friends?fields=installed](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends%3Ffields%3Dinstalled)* which should return a list of users, the ones that have the app installed will have this form:

```
{
    "installed": true, 
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

The ones who don't have the app will be of this form:

```
{
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

Then iterate over the list, check how many have it, if it's 0 then don't show the dialog.

(2) You can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) to check who are the friends who don't have the app installed using [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20not%20is_app_user%20and%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29):

```
SELECT 
    uid
FROM 
    user 
WHERE 
    not is_app_user 
    AND 
    uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

If the result is an empty string then all of the friends have the app.